# Saving Email Template as PDF attachment to record?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to save an Email template as a PDF attachment to a record ?

Answer (score 1):

@Srujan Sujju Yes, It's possible refer below code.

```
// Construct the list of emails we want to send
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMsgs = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    msg.setTemplateId( [select id from EmailTemplate where Name='abc'].id );

    msg.setWhatId('your WhatId');
    msg.setTargetObjectId('Target object record id');
    msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{'noreplay@abc.com'});
    msg.saveAsActivity = false;
    lstMsgs.add(msg);
    // Send the emails in a transaction, then roll it back
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    Messaging.sendEmail(lstMsgs);
    Database.rollback(sp);
    // For each SingleEmailMessage that was just populated by the sendEmail() method, copy its
    // contents to a new SingleEmailMessage. Then send those new messages.
    string body = lstMsgs[0].getHTMLBody();

    Attachemnt att = new Attachment();
    att.body = body;
    att.ParentID = "Your Record Id"
    insert att.
```

Comment: What type of Email Template can I use ? Will it work will all types ?

Comment: is it gethtmlbody or sethtmlbody ?

Comment: string body = msg.getHTMLBody();
the body is always null .